# Firefox didn't pop up when I start selenium test by windows task scheduler

Tags: java, windows-7, selenium, command-line, windows-task-scheduler

I am right now using windows 7 machine. And I was trying to start the selenium test by task scheduler. I used a bat file to include all the command I need to compile and run the selenium test. And for the selenium test, I use java. So what's in the script would be like

```
cd C:\Users\test\Documents\SevOneNMS\qa\automation  
C:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\javac -d C:\Users\test\Documents\tmp -classpath .;../../../jars/junit-4.11.jar;../../../jars/jsch-0.1.49.jar;../../../jars/commons-net-3.1.jar;../../../jars/selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar;tmp;../../../config tests/alerts/AlertActions.java

cd C:\Users\test\Documents\tmp   
java -classpath .;../jars/junit-4.11.jar;../jars/jsch-0.1.49.jar;../jars/commons-net-3.1.jar;../jars/selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore tests.alerts.AlertActions
```

when I run this bat file directly under windows 7, it works perfectly fine. But when start it by task scheduler, the command line widows only pop up for half second and disappeared, there is no error message and test was not executed at all.
    Below is the command line for task scheduler(Testing.bat is the bat file I'm talking about). And I don't why it's not working. Please help.

```
schtasks /create /tr Testing.bat /tn selenium /sc ONCE /st 05:55 /f

schtasks /run /tn selenium

schtasks /delete /tn selenium /f
```

Comment: I suppose the environment is not the same between task scheduler account and your account: PATH, JAVA_HOME...

Comment: Hi, Aubin, I am using the same user account actually. Furthermore, I created one bat file (cal.bat) includes only one line: calc. And I used bat file below to execute cal.bat, but the calculate application didn't start.                                     schtasks /create /tr cal.bat /tn selenium /sc ONCE /st 05:55 /f
schtasks /run /tn selenium

Comment: Try to put absolute path into cal.bat

Comment: When I put absolute path in the bat fie that starts the ca.bat, it works!!

Comment: It's because the current directory isn't set by task scheduler when it's set by explorer.exe when you double click the batch file

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I would post the answer and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Aubin, when I use the absolute path for /tr argument in schtasks.ext, everything works. And

> It's because the current directory isn't set by task scheduler when
>   it's set by explorer.exe when you double click the batch file .